# Losing texts when enumerating EMF

Tags: c++, winapi, .emf

I'm enumerating [invoice.emf](http://www.mediafire.com/?kdjwvvo7odyvwa6) and copy it to another but the texts lost. Surprisingly when I output it to a window, it draws perfectly.

```
int CALLBACK EnhMetaFileProc(HDC hdc, HANDLETABLE *pHandleTable, CONST ENHMETARECORD *pEMFRecord, int iHandles, LPARAM pData)
{
    if(pEMFRecord->iType != EMR_HEADER && pEMFRecord->iType != EMR_EOF)
    {
        PlayEnhMetaFileRecord(hdc, pHandleTable, pEMFRecord, iHandles);     
    }

    return TRUE;
}

/////// Draw on window /////////
void EnumeratingEMFOnWindow(HWND hwndScreen, HDC hdcScreen, TCHAR *srcFile, TCHAR *desFile)
{
    RECT rect;
    HENHMETAFILE hemf;
    GetClientRect(hwndScreen, &rect);   
    hemf = GetEnhMetaFile(srcFile);
    EnumEnhMetaFile(hdcScreen, hemf, EnhMetaFileProc, NULL, &rect);

    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf);
}

///// Draw on EMF ////////
void EnumeratingEMFOnEMF1(TCHAR *srcFile, TCHAR *desFile)
{
    HENHMETAFILE hemfOld, hemf;
    ENHMETAHEADER emh;
    HDC hdcEMF;

    hemfOld = GetEnhMetaFile(srcFile);
    GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hemfOld, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER), &emh);
    hdcEMF = CreateEnhMetaFile(NULL, desFile, NULL, _T("EnumeratingEMF.exe\0Something\0"));
    EnumEnhMetaFile(hdcEMF, hemfOld, EnhMetaFileProc, NULL, (RECT *)&emh.rclBounds);

    hemf = CloseEnhMetaFile(hdcEMF);    
    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf);
    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemfOld);
}

void Map10um(HDC hDC, RECT & rect)
{
    int widthmm    = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZSIZE);
    int heightmm   = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTSIZE);
    int widthpixel = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES);
    int heightpixel= GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES);

    LPtoDP(hDC, (POINT *) & rect, 2); // map from logical to device

    rect.left  =(rect.left  *widthmm *100+widthpixel/2)  / widthpixel;
    rect.right =(rect.right *widthmm *100+widthpixel/2)  / widthpixel;
    rect.top   =(rect.top   *heightmm*100+heightpixel/2) / heightpixel;
    rect.bottom=(rect.bottom*heightmm*100+heightpixel/2) / heightpixel;
}
```

I tried to inspect the records in the EMF, it results in:

```
EMR_HEADER
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_SETBRUSHORGEX
EMR_SETICMMODE
EMR_SETCOLORSPACE
EMR_RESERVED_119
EMR_SETVIEWPORTORGEX
EMR_SETVIEWPORTORGEX
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SAVEDC
EMR_INTERSECTCLIPRECT
EMR_CREATEPALETTE
EMR_SELECTPALETTE
EMR_REALIZEPALETTE
EMR_SETSTRETCHBLTMODE
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_SELECTPALETTE
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_RESTOREDC
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_EXTCREATEFONTINDIRECTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_MOVETOEX
EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETTEXTCOLOR
EMR_SETTEXTALIGN
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_CREATEBRUSHINDIRECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_CREATEPEN
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_RECTANGLE
EMR_SETBKMODE
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_SELECTOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_DELETEOBJECT
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_STRETCHDIBITS
EMR_EOF
```

**The question is: Why it draws perfectly in a window whereas it loses texts in other EMF?** 
Anything secret in invoice.emf?

Comment: Hi Emerald, do you have any updates on this? Facing a similar problem.

Comment: I might have an update, read about EMF+ records that are received as GDI Comments.